# Is this is the correct way to create a user in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

Since I'm testing the sql script I first drop the instance and users with:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE online_dev FROM dbIdsManager;
DROP USER dbIdsManager;
```

Then I create the database online_dev and the tables.
After this I create the user like this:

```
CREATE USER dbIdsManager WITH PASSWORD 'abc123' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
ALTER ROLE dbIdsManager IN DATABASE online_dev SET search_path TO map_id_db;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE online_dev TO dbIdsManager;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA map_id_db TO dbIdsManager;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA map_id_db TO dbIdsManager;
```

And everytime I try to login with that user it's says that the password is not correct.

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dbIdsManager" 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dbIdsManager"

Please enter the password for the user 'dbIdsManager' to connect the server - "dbtest"
```

There are posts that it might be an error with the 'valid until' but I already add the 'infinity' validation.

Any ideas of what it might be the problem?

The server is an instance of aws rdbms.

Answer (score 1):

The permission setting is not right.

My solution is following,

```
CREATE USER dbIdsManager WITH PASSWORD 'abc123' VALID UNTIL 'infinity' LOGIN;
```

If not specified `LOGIN` or `NOLOGIN`, `NOLOGIN` is default.

Comment: I need to log using lower case in the user name, even if the query to create it has capital letters, dunnoy why. Anyway, thanks for your reply